# Why Google Ad Manager Income not Show in Adsense

Tags: adsense, google-ad-manager

I have a blog [hazabarolo.com](https://www.hazabarolo.com/) and I am new on Google Ad Manager. In my Google Ad Manager Dashboard, I have see my Daily Income. But When I go my adsense  I can not see Google Ad Manager Income. 
[image]Please any can help me to understand me.

Answer (score 0):

Adsense, as an adnetwork, is not able to get the same data than Ad Manager, the adserver.  Quick reminder of each role :

1. Google Ad Manager is an adserver : its role is to handle ad inventories and manage/prioritize campaigns on your site. Ad Manager is able to gather statistics on what delivered on your placements.
2. Google AdSense is an adnetwork : its role is to fill your inventory with ads and provide you revenue. Adsense is only able to gather statistics about its own campaigns.

Everything is detailed [here](https://support.google.com/admanager/answer/9234653?hl=en&ref_topic=7506091).